# LLDB: printing a vector referenced by a shared_ptr

Tags: c++, debugging, shared-ptr, lldb

Having in my code something like this:

```
shared_ptr<vector<unsigned int>> f = 
    make_shared<vector<unsigned int>>();
```

how can I pretty print the vector where I can only access the shared_ptr object with

```
 frame variable f
```

and

```
 frame variable f.__ptr_->size()

 call to a function 'std::__1::vector<unsigned long, std::__1::allocator<unsigned long> >::size() const' that is not present in the target
```

gets this error?

Answer (score 7):

Given this code snippet:

```
#include <vector>
#include <memory>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    shared_ptr<vector<unsigned int> > f = 
        make_shared<vector<unsigned int> >();
    f->push_back(1);
    f->push_back(1);
    f->push_back(1);
    return 0;
}
```

LLDB just works for me:

```
(lldb) fr var
(std::__1::shared_ptr<std::__1::vector<unsigned int, std::__1::allocator<unsigned int> > >) f = 0x00000001001038c8 size=3 (strong=1 weak=1) {
  __ptr_ = 0x00000001001038c8 size=3
}
```

Even better, if I expand the *_*_ptr_:

```
(lldb) fr var --ptr-depth=2 
(std::__1::shared_ptr<std::__1::vector<unsigned int, std::__1::allocator<unsigned int> > >) f = 0x00000001001038c8 size=3 (strong=1 weak=1) {   __ptr_ = 0x00000001001038c8 size=3 {
    [0] = 1
    [1] = 1
    [2] = 1   } }
```

Comment: which version of lldb are you using?

Comment: Enrico's example works correctly for me with Xcode 5.0 (lldb-300.2.53).